# How to add data to datatable using a bootstrap model dialog?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, modal-dialog

How to add data to jquery datatable dynamically using a model dialog without saving and returning the view in mvc ?

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-url="@Url.Action("Create","POPM_Trn_IOU_Items")" id="btnCreateAsset">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Asset
                    </button>


    <div class="glyphicon-modal-window" id="createAssetModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CreateAssetModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">

        <div id="createAssetContainer">

        </div>
    </div>     
                    @*<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0">*@
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Item</th>
                            <th>Unit</th>

                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Cost</th>                               
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @if (Model.IouItems != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in Model.IouItems)
                            {
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>   
                                <td style="text-align:center">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.POPM_Item_ItemName)

                                </td>

                                <td style="text-align:center">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.POPM_Item_ItemUnit)
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align:center">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.POPM_Item_Quantity)

                                </td>

                                <td style="text-align:center">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.POPM_Item_ItemCost)
                                </td>

                                <td style="text-align:center">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item_ID)
                                </td>


                </table>

        </div>
```

JS `$(document).on('click', '#btnCreateAsset', function () {
                var url = $(this).data("url"); $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $('#createAssetContainer').html(data);

```
                event.preventDefault();
                jQuery.noConflict();
                var myBookId = $(this).data('k');
                $(".modal-body #a").val(myBookId);
                $('#createAssetModal').modal('show');
            });
        });``
```

Comment: have you tried any code?

Comment: Please post whatever code you have done. A one line text can not explain what you need to do.

Comment: yes but its save from model and return the view with datatable. datatables editor has this option built in i guess but its an paid version and too expensive.

Comment: I have put the code i already did. please help.